# Does Junit test classes available which are used for jdk 1.6 or 1.7

Tags: for-loop, junit, java, codebase

Is there any way to get junit test classes used to test jdk1.6 code base.

JDK is coming with src.zip, in the same way can I get test.zip which contains all test cases for all jdk classes.

Comment: im not really sure how your question is related to this website. it seems to me that you want a google search.

if you want help with code, post your code here and you may get some help, otherwise, im not sure how you can be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [Java  Technology Compatibility Kit](http://jcp.org/en/resources/tdk) (of TCK for short).